# WSACleanup called from dependent library close unintentionally MySQL connection

Tags: winapi, winsockets, wsastartup, wsacleanup

I have a desktop application which use MySQL database. The application worked fine unless I add a new dependency which is a dll library which communicates with special hardware using socket. This new library call [WSAStartup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213(v=vs.85).aspx) and [WSACleanup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741549(v=vs.85).aspx) to start and stop communication with the hardware.

But sometimes the connection to MySQL database is interrupted as well.

**What are the guidelines for application which use more than one dependency working with winsockets?**

Should these libraries call WSAStartup and WSACleanup?

Comment: The "sometimes" clause doesn't help much.  But you have an indication that WSACleanup() is called once too often.  Most typically because somebody is ignoring a failure return code from WSAStartup().  You can protect yourself against this by calling WSAStartup() yourself.

Comment: OK, I understand, for every successful WSAStartup  should be one WSACleanup call. Am I right?

Comment: @qub1n: Yes. They must be balanced.